# Android Xmodem file transfer over Bluetooth

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, file-transfer, xmodem

Im building an android app to send files to my device over bluetooth. This sounds simple enough, however the device can only receive data with the XMODEM file transfer protocol.

After extensive searching, I have not found any useful resources or examples of this working

My question is: has anyone ever successfully sent files over bluetooth with and android using XMODEM ftp?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I know it has been a long time but do you remember how you solve your problem?

Comment: HHey @alain no I never found a solution

Comment: XMODEM is a rather simple protocol to implement on Bluetooth SPP.  I suggest that you code it yourself and ask questions about that implementation.  Requests for libraries are off-topic. You question "has anyone ever sucessfully..."; yes I have contacted an app developer to do exactly that; they did it by porting my C++ XMODEM-1K code used on the embedded device to Kotlin that the app was written in.